# Questions about fscanf. Which of the two is better?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a freshman and I need some help regarding *fscanf*. I need to scan a txt file with multiple lines. Which of the two is better?

Let's assume the variables are declared and stdio.h is included.

CODE 1:

```
while (fscanf(pSource, "%c%c%c%c%c%c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4, &c5, &c6) == 6)
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c", c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6);
```

CODE 2:

```
int res; //note the change, I included a new variable
while ((res = fscanf(pSource, "%c%c%c%c%c%c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4, &c5, &c6)) == 6)
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c", c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6);
```

Let's assume that pSource points to this txt file:

```
A = 3
D = 2
F = 1
G = 1
```

Do I need to declare each character and scan to each one? Can't I just scan a line to a string? Since they are all considered characters in the txt file?

If you have a better-looking code or in general a more preferred one, please teach me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use fgets(). You can see the documentation [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to declare each character and scan to each one?

No.  One could code that way, but that is not flexible.

> Can't I just scan a line to a string?

Good idea.  `*scanf()` is difficult to use to read a *line*.  `fgets()` is the right tool.

> Since they are all considered characters in the txt file?

Yes, yet the data certainly implies there is a letter and number to read.

---

> Which of the two is better?

Neither.  Both simply read 6 characters with no idea about reading/detecting a *line*.

A 3rd alternative would read the *line* with `fgets()` and then parse the *string*.

```
#define LINE_SIZE 80
char buffer[LINE_SIZE];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pSource)) {
  char letter;
  int value;
  if (sscanf(buffer, " %c = %d", &letter, &number) == 2) {
    printf("Success %c %d\n", letter, number);
  } else {
    printf("Fail <%s>\n", buffer);
  }
}
```